# Clarification on going from differential form to variational form PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am taking a class on FE PDE and I just have some hopefully easy questions on some specifics of going from the strong or differential form to the weak or variational form.

The equation I am evaluating is:

-u"(x) + u(x) = f(x)         ,     u(0) = u(1) = 0

to go to the weak form I believe I should multiply by a test function, then integrate by parts and simplify what I can.  Doing this with v(x) being the test function and dropping the function of x bit

-u"v + uv = fv

IBP

∫(u'v') - |vu' + ∫(uv) = ∫(fv)

the solution given in class to this problem is

(u',v') + (u,v) = (f,v)

My question is first I assume this is inner product notation?  Where
(u,v) = ∫ ( u(x)*v(x) dx)

secondly how does the value v*u' drop out when evaluated over the domain (0-1) ?

and thirdly can someone just kind of walk me through how to derive this?  Or if its just a condition on v(x) the weighting function?

∀ v(x)∈ H_0^1 (0,1)

H_0^1 (0,1)=  {(v(x)  , v(0)=v(1)=0 , ∫v^2 dx < ∞)}

Thanks for any help you can offer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, you are right:
$$\left( {u,v} \right) = \int\limits_0^1 {uv} dx$$

2) It drops out due to the boundary conditions. When you have homogeneous boundary conditions you choose the test functions $v$ so they also match the homogeneous boundary conditions. In your case:
$$v \in {V^0} = \left\{ {\omega :\left\| \omega  \right\| + \left\| {\omega '} \right\| < \infty ,\omega \left( 0 \right) = 0,\omega \left( 1 \right) = 0} \right\}$$
so when you integrate by parts
$$\int\limits_0^1 { - u''v} dx = \left[ { - u'v} \right]_{x = 0}^{x = 1} + \int\limits_0^1 {u'v'} dx =  - u'\left( 1 \right)\underbrace {v\left( 1 \right)}_{ = 0} + u'\left( 0 \right)v\underbrace {\left( 0 \right)}_{ = 0} + \int\limits_0^1 {u'v'} dx = \int\limits_0^1 {u'v'} dx$$

Comment: Okay great thank you for the clarification! So then when choosing a weighting function it is chosen with those specific conditions?  Is there a difference between the spaces V^0 and H^1 _0 ?

Comment: If you have $u(0)=0$ then you choose $v$ such that $v(0)=0$ and if you have $u(1)=0$ you choose $v$ such that $v(1)=0$. I don't think there is, but I'm not really sure (I have yet to study functional analysis). Anyway, it doesn't make any difference on what I've said.